# How to split a sentence by clicking on de space

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to split the sentence when i click on the space. He has to make 2 parts of the sentence. I want that i click another time on a space and then to make 3 parts of the sentence.

I've tried to search on google, stackoverflow, etc. But i don't see my answer.

So this is my code.

```js
$(function() {
  $(document).data("text", $("#editor").text())
      .on("mousedown", function() {
          $("#editor")
              .html($(this)
                  .data("text"))
      })
      .on("mouseup", function() {
          that = $("#editor");
          var sel = window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.selection();
          var o = that.text();
          var before = sel.baseOffset;
          var after = o.length - before;
          var a = o.slice(0, before);
          var b = after === 0 ? "" : o.slice(-after);
          var n = "<data>||</data>";
          var html = (after === "" ? a + n : a + n + b);
          that.html(html);
      });
})
```

```css
#editor {
  font-family: Sans;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  white-space: pre;
}
#editor > data {
  color: red;
  max-width: .1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">Hello! I am a Text!</div>
```

So i hope i've i have the sentence: Hello this is a test. And then click between 'is' and 'a': 
Hello this is 
 a test.

Comment: What is your #editor element? A `textarea`? A `div` or similar? If a `div` or similar, is it contenteditable?

Comment: Could you please also give a more intuitive example of an input and output?

Comment: I wish that the right side and the left side is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
  
  // Add element around all characters
  var text = $("#editor").text();
  var newText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    newText += `<span>${text[i]}</span>`;
  }
  $("#editor").html(newText);
  
  // If you click on a space
  $("#editor").on("click", "span", function() {
    if ($(this).text() == " ") {
      var before = $(this).prevAll().reverse();
      var after = $(this).nextAll()
      $("#editor").html("");
      
      before.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("white")) {
          $("#editor").append(`<span class="yellow">${$(this).text()}</span>`);  
        } else {
          $("#editor").append(`<span class="white">${$(this).text()}</span>`);
        }
      });
      
      $("#editor").append(`<span class="white"> </span>`);
      
      after.each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("white")) {
          $("#editor").append(`<span class="yellow">${$(this).text()}</span>`);
        } else {
          $("#editor").append(`<span class="white">${$(this).text()}</span>`);
        }
       });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#editor {
  font-family: Sans;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  white-space: pre;
}
#editor .br {
  color: red;
  max-width: .1em;
}

#editor .yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#editor .white {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">Hello! I am a Text</div>
```

--- Old answer below

This should be a good start. You can do whatever you want with the variables `before` and `after` - so that is suits your case.

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery.fn.reverse = [].reverse;
  
  // Add element around all characters
  var text = $("#editor").text();
  var newText = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    newText += `<span>${text[i]}</span>`;
  }
  $("#editor").html(newText);
  
  // If you click on a space
  $("#editor").on("click", "span", function() {
    if ($(this).text() == " ") {
      var before = $(this).prevAll().reverse();
      var after = $(this).nextAll()
      $("#editor").html("");
      
      before.each(function() {
        $("#editor").append(`<span>${$(this).text()}</span>`);
      });
      
      $("#editor").append(`<span class="br">|</span>`);
      
      after.each(function() {
        $("#editor").append(`<span>${$(this).text()}</span>`);
      });
    }
  });
})
```

```css
#editor {
  font-family: Sans;
  font-size: 28px;
  letter-spacing: 8px;
  white-space: pre;
}
#editor .br {
  color: red;
  max-width: .1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">Hello! I am a Text</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, thats a good start. But i like to know how i can make the parts of the sentence are selected when i click

Comment: Selected how? By background color? If you can explain more, I can update my answer.

Comment: Uuuh yeah cind a. I would like background of the parts of the sentence's, but you can distinguish the pieces.

Comment: @JurrianD, I've updated my answer like the picture you linked to.

Comment: Thanks mate! This helps me a lot!!

Comment: It is only not working on my localhost :{ , I have all the libaries that needs but i dont know why its not working.

Comment: Is it posible to add the class white by clicking another time when it is yellow?